# Google search doesn't show Arabic home page search results in multilanguage website built with Yii1

Tags: php, seo, google-search, yii1.x

I have built a multilanguage website using Yii1 PHP framework, it supports both Arabic and English. Every URL in the site has a form: `www.example.com/lang/(title_of_page OR something like slug for the articles/news)`

Except home page for English and Arabic, that has the same url: `www.example.com`. The user can change the language, so the language of site will be changed and the page will be reloaded with another language, but it keeps the same url.

Problem: Home page with Arabic language doesn't appear on Google Arabic search but page with English does.

I have used xml-sitemap online tool to make a sitemap file from website URLs but I found that all Arabic URLs couldn't be crawled.

Does this problem appear because I have the same URL for home page for every language or could be another reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no SEO master, but it may be the cause, that the site's language depends on cookies and don't know how Google likes that.

Searched a bit for an official information and I found [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en) link of Google which states:

> Keep the content for each language on separate URLs. Don’t use cookies
>   to show translated versions of the page. Consider cross-linking each
>   language version of a page. That way, a French user who lands on the
>   German version of your page can get to the right language version with
>   a single click.

So the answer is simple, don't use the same URL when changing language on the home page. I don't know your site, what it's main language, but I think you should make a primary language with `www.example.com` URL and secondary languages with base URL like `www.example.com/lang/`.

Comment: I'd like to think you for your response, yes the problem because google get only English version of my home page,so i make another link for Arabic home,and it's work in site map generator online tool,it could get Arabic urls,but it will coast me rebuilt some structures in my website.